# Grand Total showing NaN Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam working on an application, in the Grand Total field, its showing the sum of all the margin fields totals. But when the page loads its showing NaN in the total field. How can i show the existing total to show up in the Grand Total field?

This is my script.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/eb8gaon5/5/)

`js`

```
function getIndexedElement(item, index) {
     if (item.length) {
         if (index < item.length) {
             return item[index];
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     } else {
         if (index === 0) {
             return item;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }

 function isNum(value) {
     return 123;
 }

 function calcTotals() {
     var grandTotal = 0;
     var margin_total = 0;
     var total_inr1 = 0;
     var i = 0;

     while (getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['add_percentage[]'], i)) {
         add_percentageObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['add_percentage[]'], i);
         addon_valueObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['addon_value[]'], i);
         total_inr_valueObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['total_inr[]'], i);

         totalObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['add_value[]'], i);
         priceunitObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['price_unit[]'], i);

         qtyObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['qty[]'], i);
         marginObj = getIndexedElement(document.forms['cart'].elements['margin_for[]'], i);


         if (isNaN(add_percentageObj.value)) {
             add_percentageObj = '';
         }
         if (isNaN(addon_valueObj.value)) {
             addon_valueObj = '';
         }

         if (add_percentageObj.value != 0) {
             totalObj.value = (((total_inr_valueObj.value * 1) * add_percentageObj.value / 100) + total_inr_valueObj.value * 1).toFixed(3);
             grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat(totalObj.value);
             marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);

             margin_total = ((margin_total * 1) + marginObj.value * 1);
             //total_inr1 = total_inr1 + parseFloat(total_inr_valueObj.value);
             //c.value=Math.round((b.value/100) *a.value ).toFixed(2);

         } else if (addon_valueObj.value != 0) {
             totalObj.value = ((addon_valueObj.value * 1) + total_inr_valueObj.value * 1).toFixed(3);
             grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat(totalObj.value);
             marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);

             margin_total = ((margin_total * 1) + marginObj.value * 1);
             //total_inr1 = total_inr1 + parseFloat(total_inr_valueObj.value);

         } else {
             totalObj.value = ((addon_valueObj.value * 1) + total_inr_valueObj.value * 1).toFixed(3);
             grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat(totalObj.value);
             marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);

             margin_total = ((margin_total * 1) + marginObj.value * 1);
             //total_inr1 = total_inr1 + parseFloat(total_inr_valueObj.value);

         }

         i++;
     }

     //document.getElementById('grand_total').value = grandTotal.toFixed(3);
     //document.getElementById('margin_total').value = margin_total.toFixed(3);
     //document.getElementById('total_inr1').value = total_inr1.toFixed(3);
     //document.getElementById('margin_for').value = margin_for;

     marginTotal();

     return;
 }

 function marginTotal() {

     var x = $('[name="gt[]"]:checked').length;
     if (x != 0) return;
     var sum = 0;
     $('input[name="margin_for[]"]').each(function () {
         sum += +this.value;
     });
     $("#total12").val(sum);




 }
 $(function () {
     $("input[type='checkbox'").on("change", function () {
         recalcTotal();
     }).change();

     function recalcTotal() {
         var total12 = 0;
         var checkedinput = $("input:checked");
         var targetcheckboxes = checkedinput.length ? checkedinput : $("input:checkbox");
         targetcheckboxes.each(function () {
             total12 += parseFloat($(this).next("input").val(), 10) * 1;
         });

         $("#total12").val(total12.toFixed(3));

     }
 });

 $(window).load(function () {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("select").on('change', function () {

             var dept_number = $(this).val();
             var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');

             var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

             if (selected == "INR") {
                 $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val());

             } else {

                 $(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val((($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val() * price) / $(this).closest('table').find('.inrvalue').val()).toFixed(3));
             }

             $(this).closest('table').find('.price_unit').val(($(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val() / $(this).closest('table').find('.qty').val()).toFixed(3));

         });
     });
 }); //]]>
```

In the fiddle you can see the last field, that is margin field. And extreme down you can see the Grand Total. Page Load its showing NaN..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply need to check input value next to checkbox whether its isNaN() or not
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eb8gaon5/9/)
 There are many bugs like if you enter Text in Total colum you get NaN in textbox beside checkbox as well in Grandtotal since your updating it after change in input you need to validate the textbox on change

```
         targetcheckboxes.each(function () {
             var temp=$(this).next("input").val();
             if(temp){
                total12 += parseFloat(temp, 10) * 1;
             }
         });
         $("#total12").val(total12.toFixed(3));
```

Comment: plus one as you gave him a JS soluton

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
So I was wrong, after some more testing its just that your first 3 `readonly` checkboxes don't have `value=0.000` as an attribute.

As they are `text` inputs, javascript doesn't automatically assume that an empty input is equal to 0.

just add `value=0.000` to the first three checkboxes

---

**INCORRECT OLD ANSWER**
In your `targetcheckboxes.each()` loop, your expression:
`total12 += parseFloat($(this).next("input").val(), 10) * 1;`

is causing the problem.

`next("input")` will match any type of input including text inputs. somewhere along the line you are concatenating a string to your `total12` variable and hence the final value of `total12` can not be parsed to a float.

Comment: Can u be little more specific. I learned jquery/javascript a bit and did this. Not much comfortable with scripting. Can u give me an example on how to solve this?

Comment: I could get it work with CY5 's code...its working fine now. Thank you for ur time and help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

```
parseInt(yourvalue);
parseFloat(yourvalue).toFixed(2);
```

whenever you are calculating something using js

Comment: The issue here is even i need to calculate the decimals, i had some problem with ParseInt, so converted to ParseFloat. Is there any solution to my issue?

Comment: as the OP has said, `parseInt()` should definitely not be used here as it will first convert `float`s to `int`s and the calcs will be wrong